# Get unique result from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table in mysql

```
Table A
---------
a
b

Table B 
-------
a
b
c
```

I want result uncommon field

```
Result
------
c
```

Answer (score 0):

If table_a and table_b have a column called `mycol`

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT mycol FROM
(
    SELECT mycol FROM table_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mycol FROM table_b
) A GROUP BY mycol HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS gautam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE gautam;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> USE gautam
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE table_a
    -> (
    ->     mycol CHAR(1)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.47 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE table_b LIKE table_a;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ('a'),('b');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT mycol FROM
-> (
->     SELECT mycol FROM table_a
->     UNION ALL
->     SELECT mycol FROM table_b
-> ) A GROUP BY mycol HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
+-------+
| mycol |
+-------+
| c     |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.col = b.col)
```

If you want it both ways, you can use `union all`:

```
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.col = b.col)
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where a.col = b.col)
```

These queries will take advantage of an index on the appropriate columns, if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in which table the match came from, the type of `JOIN` you are after is the rarest of beasts, the `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which can be written as:

```
SELECT <table1>.<key>, <table2>.<key>
FROM <table1> FULL OUTER JOIN <table2> ON <table1>.<key> = <table2>.<key>
WHERE <table1>.<key> IS NULL OR <table2>.<key> is null
```

For example, if you had two tables, one with keys in the range 15 - 24, and the other with keys in the range 17 - 25, this will give results like:

```
| Key 1  |  Key 2 |
|--------|--------|
|    15  |   NULL |
|    16  |   NULL |
|  NULL  |     25 |
```

If you want just the missing keys all in one column, your best bet is a `UNION` as suggested by the first poster.

A good discussion of `JOIN` types can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0):

For finding if there is anything extra in table B (which is all that your example demonstrates):

```
SELECT B.*
    FROM A
    RIGHT JOIN B USING (id)
    WHERE A.id IS NULL
```